# I get error after maximaze form from tray icon

Tags: windows, delphi, notifications

On Windows 10, when I double-click on my app's tray icon, I get an exception:

> Cannot remove shell notification icon

I noticed that the error happens when my icon is the only one in the tray. If, for example, there is another application in the tray (for example, the Task Manager), then everything is fine.

Here is the code when I double-click the icon. Framed `try except` to get the message, otherwise it crashes without exception.

```
procedure TForm1.TrayIcon1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    TrayIcon1.Visible := False;
    Show();
    WindowState := wsNormal;
    Application.BringToFront();
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I have never liked the `TTrayIcon` component. Too many people having too many problems with it over the years. I have never used it myself, I always use the Win32 `Shell_NotifyIcon()` function directly, and have never had a problem with that.

Comment: Why do you want to react on a *double-click*? Have you tried *single-click* (and not react at all on *double-click*)?

Comment: @TomBrunberg: It is common that a notification icon responds to a double-click. Typically this activates the same action as the boldfaced menu item in the icon's context menu. (At least this was the case in the  9x era.)

Comment: @Andreas Ok, if you say so. My notification icons reacts to single clicks, e.g. Windows Security opens the settings window. (It also reacts to double clicks, opening the same settings window)

Comment: @Tom: It might have been more common in the early days of the Win 95-like Explorer. On my current system, only the Microsoft Outlook 2010 icon behaves like this. A single click brings up the context menu. The `Open Outlook` item is in boldface. Double-clicking the icon (or choosing the boldface context menu item) opens Outlook.

Comment: "A single click brings up the context menu" is surely ill designed - only a single **right** click should bring up a context menu. Just like with a system menu: you'd double click the icon/left corner of the window title to select the bolded entry of its context menu, but one click alone does not bring up a context menu.

Comment: @AmigoJack Initialy it was more common that only right click brought context menu of a tray icon. But in recent years this is less and less common. I'm guessing the reason for this is the fact that laptops are becoming more popular. And since most newer laptops are equipped with button-less trackpads on which making a right click isn't as easy. Not to mention that many moder computers have built in screen based touch support on which making a right click also isn't as easy.

Comment: @SilverWarior that would be a step backwards (decades ago mouses had no right button either, but now it should be normal again?) and a wrong reasoning (screens are a different input device to begin with which will neither fully emulate keyboards, nor mouses). If current Windows versions' UI wouldn't be so crippled one would still be able to reach task icons via keyboard only, including pressing the context menu key, if not boykott buying ill designed hardware (laptops without mouse buttons) right away. Which target audience is okay with all this imprecise input and still accesses a task icon?

Comment: @AmigoJack You can still reach task icons only with keyboard. How? Minimize all windows using Win+D keyboard shortcut and then press TAB key three times. Pressing TAB key for the first time removes focus from desktop icons. Second press of TAB key switch focus to TaksBar buttons/icons. And third press of TAB key moves focus to Try icons. Then just use arrow keys to move between different icons and execute action using Space key.

Comment: @AmigoJack What I was talking about is not so much of features being removed from Windows but the shift on which kind od devices Windows is used mostly these days. Also you shouldn't forget that with release of Windows 8 and later Windows 10 Microsoft is trying to make OS that could be ran both on Desktop/Laptops as well as on mobile devices. And in order to achieve this the UI needs to be designed in a way that it is accessible on all devices equally.

Comment: @SilverWarior: No need to show desktop (Win+D). Win+T will set focus to the taskbar. Then you can tab your way to the notification area.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Well that I didn't knew. It will come in handy :-)